The protective DNS Service is blocking my site; how can I stop this?
I have created a personal website for the purpose of coordinating an event. The SSL certificates for this website are set up correctly and the website can be accessed from most devices I have checked. One exception is that people using eduroam inside the United Kingdom run into the error shown in the image below.
I have found on the website of the UK National Cyber Security Center that "Protective DNS is a recursive DNS resolver which prevents access to domains known to be malicious.".
I have published my website just today so I do not see how it would end up on such a block list so quickly (especially since it is not even malicious!). The one explanation I can imagine is that since my site is hosted on a server on the name of *.zxcs.nl, the Protective DNS might be recursively blocking me if some other site also hosted at *.zxcs.nl is hosting malicious content.
Is there anything I can do to make my website not be blocked by the Protective DNS Service?

I ran the Cloudflare Radar and it said there were no known issues with my website.


Have you already tried the message's suggestion to look up your site on Cloudflare Radar for more information?

@grawity Yes, I went to cloudflare radar and it says my site is not classified yet. (I also editted the post now)

Do all institutions in UK use some kind of centralized DNS setup for their eduroam SSIDs? Does this happen across several different institutions?

@grawity I'm not sure. I have, to be honest, only checked one university (oxford)

I'd expect it to be managed locally by Oxford IT then. It might differ by country, but generally eduroam only provides central authentication servers (and that only partially), while the rest of the network infrastructure is provided by the local institution you visit – i.e. "eduroam at Oxford" is most likely just regular Oxford University Wi-Fi with central accounts – so if it looks like they might have set up a custom DNS filter, then you'd need to ask them specifically about that.

I’m voting to close this question because its more suited to Webmasters site
